# If a sequence converges, then every subsequence converges to the same limit -- but how do I know a subsequence exists?

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis, convergence-divergence

I have been reading the following post:

[Prove: If a sequence converges, then every subsequence converges to the same limit.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/213285/prove-if-a-sequence-converges-then-every-subsequence-converges-to-the-same-lim)

I understand the idea, but I wonder, does this proof imply that such a subsequence actually exists?

That is, suppose a sequence $s_n$ converges. Then every subsequence $s_{n_k}$  of $s_n$ converges to the same limit. But my question is: does there necessarily exist such a subsequence $s_{n_k}$?

Comment: Take the subsequence to equal the sequence. So, you have one.. Remove a term from the sequence, then you have another subsequence of the sequence. Remove a finite number of terms to get a third subsequence.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take your sequence $s_n$. It is nonempty. Therefore it has a subsequence.

Comment: What do you mean by "[the sequence is] nonempty"?

Comment: @PedroTamaroff So long as the $s_n$ is not the empty sequence.

Comment: I know this is a long time after the fact, but what exactly is "the empty sequence"?

Comment: @CameronBuie a sequence in which the set of points is nonempty? To be entirely honest with you, this is terminology I picked up from a class at the time. I could revisit my notes and see exactly what I meant, but the explanation I just offered seems sufficiently plausible...

Comment: How can a sequence have an empty set of points, though? A sequence is a function whose domain is the natural numbers, effectively, and there is no function from the natural numbers into the empty set. I would be curious what an empty sequence is supposed to be, then.

Comment: @CameronBuie Some people call functions of the form $f:\{1,...,n\} \to X$ "sequences", but then still, the term "empty sequence" doesn't make much sense...

Answer (score 2):

Some simple subsequences of $(s_n)_{n=1}^\infty$ would be

- the original sequence, $(s_n)_{n=1}^\infty$,
- the subsequences obtained by removing finitely many terms - in particular, all of the tails $(s_n)_{n=N}^\infty$ - are subsequences,
- the subsequences obtained by taking every $k$-th element, $(s_{kn})_{n=1}^\infty$.