# Proving in the formal way that a sequence is divergent

Tags: calculus

I have the following sequence (I've already put it in the $a_n - L$ form)
$$\left|\frac{(-1)^n n+1}{n + 2}-L\right|\ge\epsilon$$
I think that in order to prove that the sequence is divergent I need to prove that $\ge\epsilon$ instead of the usual $<\epsilon$
My problem is that I have L which is stuck there so Im not sure if Im supposed to make it go somehow or play along with it like its just a number which uglify my expression

Comment: this sequence converges.

Comment: @mvw I fixed the right bar

Comment: @mw This sequence converges (to 1), did you mean $a_n = (-1)^n + (n+1)/(n+2)$ which diverges?

Comment: @NigelOvermars  fixed the typo guys sorry

Comment: The divergence is of the oscillating type. You are not able to make the difference arbitrary large (as opposite to arbitrary small}. But you could show that it has two limit points.

Comment: @mvw So it means my inequality is not good from the start? how could I show it? I have to prove it in the $|\epsilon - N|$ way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Show that for all $\epsilon_{1,2}>0$ there are $N_{1,2}\in \mathbb N$ such that $ |a_{2n}-1|<\epsilon_1$ and $ |a_{2n+1}+1|<\epsilon_1$ for all $n>N_1,N_2$

Hence the sequence is divergent

That's a formal way but of course I started different as you... still okay for you?

Comment: I think it is formal enough it just means that in order to prove divergence I need to prove that there are at least 2 differnt $\epsilon$ that apply to what you said? I cant find a clear definition of divergent sequence

Comment: After you proved the existance of the two limit points, take $\epsilon_1=\epsilon_2=0.5$ and see whats happens

Comment: Divergent sequence in English just seems to mean "not convergent sequence". In German there is a distinction between "bestimmt divergent" (to $-\infty$, $+\infty$) and "unbestimmt divergent" (your case), which I can not find in English so far.

Comment: @mvw I can't even find the mathematical definition (besides the not converge defintion)

Comment: A sequence with does not converge is called a divergent sequence :) So, just negate the definition of convergent sequence and you will get the solution together with my comment above.

Comment: I got $n> \frac{1}{\epsilon_1}$ and $n > \frac{3}{\epsilon_2}$ what am I supposed to see when the epsilons equal 0.5?

Comment: If we choose \epsilon_{1,2}=0,5, then for a suitable $N\in \mathbb N$, we have $|a_{2n}-1|<0.5$ and $|a_{2n+1}+1|<0.5$, hence both are not limit points, but accumulation points. Try to understand by your own why it is like this..a sketch can help and recall the definiton of convergence.

Answer (score 1):

$$
\frac{(-1)^n n+1}{n + 2}
= \frac{(-1)^n}{1+2/n} + \frac{1}{n + 2}
$$

The subsequence of odd indices converges to $-1$.
The subsequence of even indices converges to $+1$.

For the rest, read [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/213285/prove-if-a-sequence-converges-then-every-subsequence-converges-to-the-same-lim).