# Limit of $\sin(1/x)$ - why there is no limit?

Tags: calculus, limits

$$ \lim_{x\to 0+} \sin\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)$$
I know that there is no limit.

but, why there is no limit?
I tried $x=0.4$, $x=0.3$, $x=0.1$, it looks like the limit is $0$.

And how can I show that there is no limit? I tried to calculate it like all the other functions, and I got wrong result and I don't know why:

$$\lim_{x \to 0+} \sin\left(\frac{1}{x}\right) = \sin\left(\frac{1}{0^+}\right) =  \sin\left(\frac{1}{\infty}\right) = \sin(0) = 0.$$

Comment: Since when is $0^+=\infty$?

Comment: How come $\frac{1}{0+}=1/\infty$?Did you get where you went wrong?

Comment: You cannot substitute $0^+$ and $\infty$ as if they were numbers, because they actually aren't.

Comment: Try taking the limit along the sequence $x_k = \frac{1}{k \pi/2}$ with $k$ integer.

Comment: I would be highly surprised if this question isn't a duplicate.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*Why there is no limit?*

The graphic can help you understand why and suggest you some approach for the proof:

[image]

**Remark:** You have to be careful with tables of values because they can be misleading:

\begin{array}{ c | c c c c }
x &  \frac{1}{2\pi} & \frac{1}{3\pi} & \frac{1}{4\pi} &\frac{1}{5\pi} \\ \hline
 \sin\left(\frac{1}{x}\right) & 0     & 0   & 0     & 0    \\
                        \end{array}

\begin{array}{ c | c c c c }
x &  \frac{2}{5\pi} & \frac{2}{9\pi} & \frac{2}{13\pi} &\frac{2}{17\pi} \\ \hline
 \sin\left(\frac{1}{x}\right) & 1     & 1   & 1     & 1    \\
                        \end{array}

(The tables above are a sketch of the proof - see Theorem 2.4 [here](https://www.math.ucdavis.edu/~hunter/m125a/intro_analysis_ch2.pdf).)

Comment: Thank you for the nice explanation! May I ask what's the title of the book you linked? I'd be interested in the other chapters of it. Edit: Never mind, I found it here: https://www.math.ucdavis.edu/~hunter/m125a/

Answer (score 3):

That's because your limit is equivalent to $$\lim_{x\to\infty} \sin(x)$$

and $\sin$ is oscillating when $x\to\infty$.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: $\frac1x$ has a right-sided limit of $+\infty$. Does $\sin x$ have a limit for $x\to\infty$?

Answer (score 1):

You made an error.
\begin{array}{ c | c c c c }
x &  .4 & .3 & .2 &.1 \\ \hline
 \sin\left(\frac{1}{x}\right) & 0.5984721     & -0.190568   & -0.9589243     & -0.54402113    \\
                        \end{array}
This does not suggest that the limit approaches $0$.

Second, you mean to say
$$\lim_{x\to 0^+} = \sin\left(\frac{1}{x}\right) = \sin(\infty)$$
**not** $\lim_{x\to 0^+}\sin\left(\frac{1}{x}\right) = \sin\left(\frac{1}{\infty}\right).$
Recall that $$\lim_{x\to 0^+} \frac{1}{x} = \infty.$$

Answer (score 1):

Consider the two subsequences $x_k = \frac1{(4k + 1)\pi/2}$ and $x'_k = \frac1{k\pi}$ with $k \in \mathbb Z$. We have that for $k \to +\infty$, $x_k,x'_k \to 0^+$. Clearly,
$$\begin{align*}
&\lim_{k \to +\infty} \sin\left(\frac1{x_k}\right) = 1\\
&\lim_{k \to +\infty} \sin\left(\frac1{x'_k}\right) = 0
\end{align*}$$
and therefore the limit $x \to 0^+$ does not exist. We used the theorem that states that if a sequence converges, then every subsequence converges to the same limit. By modus tollens, our sequence does not converge.

More info about the theorem here:
[Prove: If a sequence converges, then every subsequence converges to the same limit.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/213285/prove-if-a-sequence-converges-then-every-subsequence-converges-to-the-same-lim)

Answer (score 1):

Lets look at $sin(\frac{1}{x}) $ function,

[image]

Now you can get a idea how it behaves near to 0. That is oscillating near 0. THat's why we can't get limit when x goes to 0 of $sin(\frac{1}{x}) $ function. So let's move into it's proof,

#### Have to prove $\lim_{x \to 0+} sin(\frac{1}{x})=Does  \: not \: exist$

$$\forall \varepsilon >0 \;  \exists \delta \; s.t \;  0< x  < \delta \mapsto |sin\frac{1}{x}-L|<\varepsilon$$

Let $\varepsilon=\frac{1}{2}$,

$$0< x   < \delta \mapsto |sin\frac{1}{x}-L|<\frac{1}{2}$$

**Assume** that, $$\lim_{x \to 0+} sin(\frac{1}{x})=L \; \in \mathbb{R}$$

Let $$x_{1}=\frac{1}{2n\pi+\frac{\pi}{2}} \; \;  (n\in Z^{+})\; \; and \; \; x_{2}=\frac{1}{2n\pi+\frac{3\pi}{2} } \; \;  (n\in Z^{+})$$
So we have to **get range of n**,
$$0<\frac{1}{2n\pi +\frac{3\pi}{2}} < \frac{1}{2n\pi+\frac{\pi}{2} }<\delta$$
$$\frac{1}{2n\pi+\frac{\pi}{2} }<\delta$$
So we get,
$$\frac{1}{2\pi\delta }-\frac{1}{4}<n\; \;  (n\in Z^{+})$$

Now,
$$|sin(x_{1})-L|=|1-L|<\frac{1}{2}\Rightarrow \mathbf{C}$$
$$|sin(x_{2})-L|=|-1-L|=|1+L|<\frac{1}{2}\Rightarrow \mathbf{D}$$
By **C** + **D** we get,
$$|1-L|+|1+L|< 1$$
$$|(1-L)+(1+L)|\leq |1-L|+|1+L|< 1$$
$$2\leq |1-L|+|1+L|< 1$$
$$2<1 \; \;\; \; (\therefore contradiction)$$

Assumption is not true. $\: \: \therefore\:\lim_{x \to 0+} sin(\frac{1}{x})$ has no limit.

Comment: Nice proof, but shouldn't it be $|\sin(\frac{1}{x_{1}})-L|=|1-L|<\frac{1}{2}$ and $|\sin(\frac{1}{x_{2}})-L|=|1+L|<\frac{1}{2}$? If not, please explain.