# If a sequence converges, then every subsequence converges to the same limit

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

[Prove: If a sequence converges, then every subsequence converges to the same limit.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/213285/prove-if-a-sequence-converges-then-every-subsequence-converges-to-the-same-lim)

Instead of saying that $n_{k}\geq k> N\implies |a_{n_{k}}-L|<\epsilon$

Can i say that

let $i$ be the smallest positive integer such that $n_{i}\geq N$,

so $n_{k}> n_{i}\geq N\implies |a_{n_{k}}-L|<\epsilon$

Comment: Didn't you just change the $k$ with an $n_i$? They basically mean the same thing (index of element/element, that is sufficiently close to $L$)

Comment: @Laray They don't always mean the same thing. It depends on the sequence and subsequence.

Comment: When you take the limit as $n_k\to\infty$, It's sufficient to find _one_ and not necessary be smallest.

Comment: @MyGlasses yes, it does not have to be the smallest, but that's not the point here.