# $(a_{(k_n)})_{n\in\mathbb N}$ converges to L?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, epsilon-delta

The problem: Suppose $(a_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ is a sequence in $\mathbb R$ moreover that $(a_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ converges to $L \in \mathbb R$. $(k_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ is a sequence in $\mathbb N$, with $\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{1}{k_n} = 0$. How can we show $(a_{(k_n)})_{n\in\mathbb N}$ converges to L?

My progress: Intuitively I can see why this is true moreover, after seeing a series of classes full of epsilon delta proofs of different limit theorems within sequences in general. I would bet that this will be a proof with creative uses of the epsilon delta definitions perhaps more than once in a nested fashion.

I've spent about 7-8hrs today on this question and have literally made no progress other than trying to bend the definition of convergence around like a mad man.

Comment: A note: as @user143234 remarked in his answer, then the convergence of $a_{k_n}$ to $L$ follows from a general theorem in mathematical analysis, which can be found also in stadard textbooks as E. Fisher’s *Intermediate real analysis*. The general argument follows from the monotonicity of $\limsup$, $\liminf$ and from the fact that since $k_n\to\infty$ then it is possible to extract from it a strictly monotonic subsequence converging to infinity. In sum, this result relies on monotonicity and thus on order arguments.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let $\epsilon >0$. There exists $m$ such that $|a_n-L| <\epsilon$ for $n >m$. There exists $p$ such that $\frac 1 {k_n} < \frac 1 m$ for $n>p$. If $n >p$ then $|a_{k_n} -L| < \epsilon$.

Answer (score 2):

If $\lim_{n} \frac{1}{k_n} \to 0$, then it is obvious that $\lim_{n} k_n \to \infty$ (you can use simple $\epsilon-\delta$ techniques to prove this). If a sequence converges, then every subsequence converges to the same limit ([Prove: If a sequence converges, then every subsequence converges to the same limit.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/213285/prove-if-a-sequence-converges-then-every-subsequence-converges-to-the-same-lim)). $\{a_{k_n}\}$ is just a subsequence, so the result follows.

Comment: This may be a technicality, but I think it's worth pointing out for these type of exercises: $(k_n)_{n \geq 1}$ need not be increasing and therefore $a_{k_n}$ is not always well defined.

Comment: Yes, thanks for pointing this out. I think strictly speaking, its not a sub-sequence

Comment: My answer shows that $\{a_{{k_n}}\}$ converges to $L$ whether or not it is a subsequence of $\{a_n\}$.

Comment: The sequence $k_n$ contains an increasing subsequence, so this argument can still be saved.

Comment: I think convergence for a sub-sequence does not imply convergence for the general sequence to the same limit

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy In context of your reply that your proof shows $\{a_{k_n}\}$ converges to $L$ regardless of the fact whether or not it is a subsequence, I would love explanation. In your proof, you say, " $\exists$ some $p$ such that $\frac 1 {k_n} < \frac 1 m$ ". I am interested in knowing how this statement still holds when the sub-index, i.e $\{k_n\}$ is not convergent?

Comment: What I am saying that $\{k_n\}$ need not be strictly increasing to $\infty$. It can even decrease in-between but the hypothesis tells us that $k_n \to \infty$ and this is crucial. In choosing $p$ I have used the fact that $k_n \to \infty$. You can use the term subsequence only when $k_n$ is strictly increasing.

Comment: I get it now! Your proof does allow the sub-index to be partly oscillatory. I messed up on the definition of subsequence. Thank you for your clarification!

Comment: @user143234 Consider the sequence $\{(-1)^n\}_n$. Here consider a subsequence with even-index, i.e $2, 4, 6, ...$. We can see that the resulting subsequence is $\{1\}_n$, which converges to $1$. Now, consider the other subsequence with odd indexing, i.e. $\{-1\}_n$, which converges to $-1$. We can readily see, that the main sequence doesn't converge anywhere but its subsequences do. Hence, we can safely say, that mere convergence of a single subsequence cannot guarantee the convergence of the parent sequence. However, it is true when every subsequence of a sequence converge to the same limit.