# Stuck at proving whether the sequence is convergent or not

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, trigonometry, convergence-divergence, limsup-and-liminf

I have been trying to determine whether the following sequence is convergent or not. This is what I got:

> **Exercise 1**: *Find the $\min,\max,\sup,\inf, \liminf,\limsup$ and determine whether the sequence is convergent or not:*
>
>   
>   $X_n=\sin\frac{n\pi}{3}-4\cos\frac{n\pi}{3}$

I wrote down a few cases:

$X_1 = \sin\frac{\pi}{3}-4\cos\frac{\pi}{3}= \frac{\sqrt3-4}{2} $

$X_2 = \sin\frac{2\pi}{3}-4\cos\frac{2\pi}{3}= \frac{\sqrt3+4}{2} $

$X_3 = \sin\frac{3\pi}{3}-4\cos\frac{3\pi}{3}=4 $

$X_4 = \sin\frac{4\pi}{3}-4\cos\frac{4\pi}{3}= \frac{4-\sqrt3}{2} $

$X_5 = \sin\frac{5\pi}{3}-4\cos\frac{5\pi}{3}= \frac{4-\sqrt3}{2} $

$X_6 = \sin\frac{6\pi}{3}-4\cos\frac{6\pi}{3}= -4 $

So as found above, $\min = -4$, $\max = 4$, $\inf = -4$, $\sup = 4$, $\liminf = -4$, $\limsup = 4$.

Let's check whether its convergent or not:
The sequence is bounded as stated above so lets check if its decreasing or increasing.

$X_n \geq X_{n+1}$

$\sin\frac{n\pi}{3}-4\cos\frac{n\pi}{3} \geq\sin\frac{(n+1)\pi}{3}-4\cos\frac{(n+1)\pi}{3}$

$\sin\frac{n\pi}{3} - \sin\frac{(n+1)\pi}{3} \geq  -4\cos\frac{(n+1)\pi}{3} + 4\cos\frac{n\pi}{3}$

I used trigonometrical identity for $\sin\alpha+\sin\beta$ and $\cos\alpha-\cos\beta$ :

$-\cos\frac{\pi(2n+1)}{6} \geq 4\sin\frac{\pi(2n+1)}{6}$

What should I do next? I am stuck here.
Thanks, and sorry if I made mistakes.

Comment: which book is this taken from ?

Comment: @J.Deff Not sure, why?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It happens that your sequence is a cyclic sequence. More precisely, its first six terms are$$-2+\frac{\sqrt3}2,2+\frac{\sqrt3}2,4,2-\frac{\sqrt3}2,-2-\frac{\sqrt3}2,\text{ and }-4$$and then it repeats itself again and again. Therefore:

- $\max\{X_n\,|\,n\in\mathbb N\}=\sup\{X_n\,|\,n\in\mathbb N\}=\limsup_nX_n=4$;
- $\min\{X_n\,|\,n\in\mathbb N\}=\inf\{X_n\,|\,n\in\mathbb N\}=\liminf_nX_n=-4$;
- the sequence diverges.

Comment: So it is even stupid to check if it converges? It is similar to alternative sequences?

Comment: No, it is not stupid and, yes, it is similar to alternate sequences.

Comment: Thank you so much. I appreciate it.

Comment: @Exzone from which book is this problem taken from ?

Comment: @J.Deff You should post this as a comment to the question, not to my answer.

Answer (score 6):

The limit of a sequence, if it exists, is equal to its lim inf and lim sup. Accordingly, if the lim inf and lim sup of a sequence are different, then its limit cannot exist.

Answer (score 4):

Computing the first $6$ terms alone does not prove that $\min X_n=-4$ nor $\max X_n=4$ but rather that $\min X_n\le-4$ and $\max X_n \ge 4$ as it does not say anything about the rest of the sequence.

Hint : $X_{n+6}=X_n$

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:** Note that this is a **periodic** sequence, meaning: $x_{n+6}=x_n$.

Therefore, this sequence **diverges**.

Comment: periodic alone is not enough to prove that the sequence diverges as constant sequences are periodic and convergent

Comment: Of course you are right, I wrore only the general idea  :)

Comment: is there a difference between "diverge" and "does not converge"?

Comment: @costrom Typically, diverge is the opposite of converge. It doesn't haven't to fail to converge in any particular way to diverge.

Comment: @Matt I figured as much. it's just a semantic thing, clearly if the sequence tends towards an unbounded value, it "diverges". If I were asked if this particular sequence diverged though, I'm not sure how I'd answer :)

Answer (score 3):

[If the sequence is convergent, then all of its subsequences should
converge to the same limit](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/213285/prove-if-a-sequence-converges-then-every-subsequence-converges-to-the-same-lim).
Consider the subsequence defined by $n_{k}=3k$:
$$
X_{n_{k}}=\sin(k\pi)-4\cos(k\pi)=-4\cos(k\pi)=\begin{cases}
-4 & \text{if }k\text{ is even}\\
+4 & \text{if }k\text{ is odd}.
\end{cases}
$$
This subsequence oscillates between the values of $-4$ and $+4$.
What does that tell you?

Comment: That subsequences do not converge to the same limit. Thanks!

Comment: Exzone: It tells you that that subsequences does not converge and therefore the original sequence does not converge either.

Comment: Yeah, gotcha! I appreciate your comment.

Comment: *that the subsequence