# Is it possible to define such an operator $\operatorname{\Gamma}$ that satisfies $ \lim_{n\to \infty} {\Gamma} (f(n))=\beta $?

Tags: operator-theory

Let, the function $f:\mathbb N^+ \longrightarrow \mathbb R$ is given. Is it possible to define such an operator $\operatorname{\Gamma}$  that satisfies the following conditions:

> For any $n\in\mathbb {N^+}$  we have
>
> $$\operatorname{\Gamma} (f(n))=\alpha$$and
>
> $$\displaystyle \lim_{n\to \infty} \operatorname{\Gamma} (f(n))=\beta $$

where $\alpha,\beta \in \mathbb R$ and $\alpha\neq \beta.$

Is this mathematically possible?

Comment: Please check [Prove: If a sequence converges, then every subsequence converges to the same limit.](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/213285/602049).

Comment: @JohnOmielan So, it is not possible?

Comment: Good work! Yes, you are correct, it's not possible. I see there's now an answer, but I hope that other post helps you understand better why it's not possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, simply because
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\Gamma(f(n)) =
\lim_{n\to\infty}\alpha = \alpha\neq\beta$$

Comment: Wrong answer. ${}$

Comment: The answer is correct for the question as asked. Perhaps you stated the question incorrectly?

Comment: Yes, you are most likely right. I may not have asked the question correctly. I accept your answer. If I want to ask new question, I will ask for a new one.