# Why isn't $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^n$ a telescoping series?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, power-series, telescopic-series

I read that the reason $\sum_{n=0}^\infty(-1)^n$ does not converge is because the terms alternate between -1 and 0. So I realize that this sentence does answer my question, but what I'm having difficulty understanding is that why wouldn't it collapse to 0 at infinity in the same way that another alternating series, even if it doesn't collapse to 0 before infinity, does?

Comment: Note that a telescoping series is defined as one in which the partial sums simplify to a fixed number of terms. So the series you gave is a telescoping series. But not every telescoping series converges. $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\ln(n) - \ln(n+1)$ is a telescoping series. But it doesn't not converge. Same with the series you've given.

Comment: it does converge, but no in the limited sense that they are teaching you. in general asking why a is not b is a wrong question, instead of asking why something is not something, ask what is it instead, it is always obvious that if is not b that means a does not satisfy the definition of what b should b. btw the value of this series 0.5 ,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the sequence $(a_n)_n$ defined as $a_n = (-1)^n.$

Now you can form the sequence of the partial sums, $(s_n)_n$, as

$$s_n = \sum_{k=1}^{n} a_k = a_1 + a_2 + \dots + a_n.$$

By definition, $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} a_n = \lim s_n.$

Let’s study the convergence of $(s_n)_{n}.$ Consider this two subsequences of $(s_{n})_{n}.$

$$s_{2n} = (-1)^{2n} = 1 \quad \quad s_{2n-1} = (-1)^{2n-1} = -1$$

As you can easily check

$$\lim s_{2n} = 1 \neq -1 = \lim s_{2n-1}.$$

So there are two subsequences of $s_n$ that converge to different values. Therefore $s_n$ does not converge.

> If a sequence converges, then every subsequence converges for the same limit.
>
> Check this for more information on this result
>
> [Prove: If a sequence converges, then every subsequence converges to the same limit.](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/213285)

Therefore $\lim s_n$ does not exist. Hence $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}$ diverges.

---

Note that in this case the cancellation of the terms in $s_n$ wouldn’t work because the result would depend on what $n$ you are deciding. That’s why this is not a telescoping series, you can’t express it as a certain amount of terms after cancellation and still have the same result

Comment: This doesn’t answer why it is not a Telescoping Series!

Comment: Note that in this case the cancellation of the terms in $s_n$ wouldn’t work because the result would depend on what $n$ you are deciding

Answer (score 1):

A telescoping series (sum) is usually defined as a *finite* series in which consecutive terms cancel, so that you are only left with the initial and final terms. The series you're considering is an infinite series. In general, you can't treat infinite series like finite series.